# How do I add jquery ui select to a drupal module

Tags: jquery-ui, drupal-7

I am porting a plugin I built originally for WordPress to a drupal 7 module.
Everything works fine except I cannot add jquery ui selectmenu:
Here is my .module code

```
<?php

function mortamCalc_menu() {
$items = array();

$items['mortam_calc/render_calculator'] = array(
    'title' => 'Hello World Test',
    'page callback' => 'render_calculator',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
 );

return $items;
}

function render_calculator() {
    $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mortamcalc');
    drupal_add_css($module_path.'/assets/css/mortamCalc.css');

    drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.datepicker');
    drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.widget');
    drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.selectmenu');

    drupal_add_js($module_path.'/assets/js/mortamCalc.js');
    ob_start();                      // start capturing output
        include('views/mortamcalc.php');   // execute the file
        $template =  ob_get_contents();    // get the contents from the buffer
    ob_end_clean();   
return $template;
}

?>
```

ui.datepicker and ui.widget load fine but ui.selectmenu is nowhere to be seen.
What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7 has a `ui.selectable` library item in the system.module. But I don't think there is any `ui.selectmenu` library available by default.

Did you add it yourself as a library item, or as part of your module? If that's the case you'd need to update that referencing line to make it work.